# How can I store bunch of jQuery code lines in a variable to use it later on the document..?

Tags: jquery, variables, append

I have something like this and i have to use this in several palaces in my jQuery code. 
I can't use function, because the  '.payment-items input' is appended after document loaded.
i want a way to reduce my code lines and increase performance and use for example a Variable instead of lots of these bunch of code lines.

```
$('.payment-items input').each(function(index){
    var value = $('.payment-items input').eq(index).val();
    var price = $('.payment-items input').eq(index).parent().find('p span').html();
    final += (value * price);
});
```

Comment: how is this input element being loaded?

Comment: i'm unsure from your example why you can't use [jquery's `.load()` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: use `load()` on what @wahwahwah ? Don't see how that would help OP situation

Comment: I can't see why a function can't be used.
Anywhere these lines are written, it can be replaced with a function running them. Problem with `$('.payment-items input')`? Get it as an argument instead of hard coding..

Comment: @wahwahwah input elements are appended under some circumstances.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez I can't use function because of appending input elements after document loaded. I tried using function but it was not useful. what you mean by get it as an argument? get what? would you please show me an example ?

Comment: @MahdiGhandi - Show some more of your code to give context, and we may be able to help..

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez
how can i show you some more?

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez
I dont know how can i show you some part of my code. the code above is unreadable.

Comment: If you had earned 20 rep, we could use the chat for that. Meanwhile, edit your question to give broader context, and also win the chance of someone other than myself giving you a better answer.

We can try this though: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91660/room-for-mahdi-ghandi-nitai-j-perez
Also, consider removing the code-comment. It's useless.